# Escaping special characters in mysql password while executing mysql query on remote host

Tags: mysql, bash, passwords, escaping, special-characters

I'm trying to run a mysql query on a remote host using a bash script.

```
${MYSQL} -u ${USER} -p${PASS} -P${PORT} -h ${HOST} -e "select * from information_schema;"
```

My PASS looks something like "dfsf#DFD". It conatins '#' character.
For some reasons the PASS is not retrieving correctly in the script. Its getting chopped off after '#'.

And for some reason including `source /etc/environment` in the script, seems to fix the problem.
I want to understand why is this happening. How to make it work without the `source` statement.

Comment: add spaces for a start e.g. `-p ${PASS}` like you have done for -u have you tried wrapping the whole string in quotes and seeing what's being output?

Comment: You need double quotes around your variable expansion like: `"$MYSQL" -u "$USER" -p "$PASS" -P "$PORT" -h "$HOST" -e 'select * from information_schema;'`

Comment: @LéaGris any idea why the problem is getting fixed after using `source /etc/environment' in the script?

Comment: Are you setting $USER $PASS etc in your local session e.g. not exporting /setting in the script?

Comment: @bobdylan i have declared those variables in `/etc/environment'

Comment: @NikhilSingh: You set the userid/password for your database in a world-readable file? Seriously?

Comment: apparently the actual issue is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300003/environment-variable-string-getting-chopped-off-because-of-special-character Not related to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - the safest way to specify remote connection details for MySQL is using configuration file: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html
So briefly you just put something like this in ~/.my.cnf file:

```
[client]
host='...'
port='...'
user='...'
password='...'
```

And then you simply run

```
mysql -e "select * from information_schema;"
```

Not sure it suits your situation, but it should solve your issue, if you quote the values.
Quoting at command line is also a solution, but your credentials will be visible to everyone able to see your processes at the system where you run that.

Comment: Apparently, the actual issue is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300003/environment-variable-string-getting-chopped-off-because-of-special-character
I agree its not the safest way. But I'm just trying things out right now. Will definitely use the advice.