# Environment variable string getting chopped off because of special character

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

In `/etc/environment` I have declared a variable "myvar" as:

`myvar='abc$#abc'`.

I need to use the varibale in a script. When I print the variable through the script, The string gets chopped off after '$' character.

`echo $myvar`

Result:

`abc$`.

Fix(But why is this working?):

When I include `source /etc/environment` in the script, the variable is retrieved correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $myvar
source /etc/environment
echo $myvar
```

Result:

```
abc$
abc$#abc
```

Why is this working? And how can I make it work without using `source`?

Comment: Looks like `myvar` declared with 'abc$' and after soucing it's getting desired value. Try this command `declare | grep myvar=` to check how `myvar` is declared.

Comment: @Ivan not getting output for that. but `printenv myvar` also gives `abc$`. PS: never declared `myvar` anywhere else for sure.

Comment: @jared_mamrot tried that. it prints `abc\$`

Comment: [escape-hash-mark-in-etc-environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97736/escape-hash-mark-in-etc-environment) should answer your question.

Comment: Why would your second script print a value for the first `echo $myvar` if you never set it? How do you execute the script?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I have declared `myvar` in /etc/environment. PS: The above comment answered my question.

Comment: Still not clear to me why your second script prints `abc$` first and not nothing. How is `myvar` declared at the point where you first `echo` it? There are no commands before the `echo` in the script.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.

Comment: Duplicate on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56688407/3266847